# Why does my check image dimension function not work with onchange dom javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to alert width and height of image using javascript but not word how can i do ?

https://jsfiddle.net/5ajak14c/

```
<input name="banner_img_ads" type="file" onchange="updateInput_banner_img_ads(this.value)">
<script>
function updateInput_banner_img_ads(image_dimension){
    var file, img;
    if ((file = image_dimension.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            alert(image_dimension.width + " " + image_dimension.height);
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
            alert( "not a valid file: " + file.type);
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your passing 'this.value' into the method?  Try just 'this'.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `this.value` to the function, so `image_dimension` is the value of the input, not the input itself.

If you use a proper event listener, it's easier

```js
document.getElementById('banner_img_ads').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var file = this.files[0], img;

  if (file) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
    };
    img.onerror = function() {
      alert("not a valid file: " + file.type);
    };
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
});
```

```html
<input name="banner_img_ads" id="banner_img_ads" type="file" />
```

Comment: can i use onchange in input ?

Comment: @roboertfer Have you looked at my solution? I'm using onchange.

Comment: @roboertfer if you like my answer you can always mark it as the correct one by clicking on the check mark picture :). Thanks!

Comment: @roboertfer - you can, but you shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. Hope it helps!

```js
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                alert($('#blah').width() + " " + $('#blah').height());
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    
function myFunction(input) {
    readURL(input);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' id="imgInp" onChange = "myFunction(this)"/>
<img id="blah" src="#" style = "display:none;"/>
```